# Slickgrid redisplay grid after deleteItem

Tags: jquery, slickgrid

I have several SlickGrids that allow User to deleteItems (actually rows).  This works fine but when User wants to cancel the deletion of the rows, I am not able to redisplay the entire grid.  Here's the relevent code to remove the rows:

```
//  Modal Grid2 Remove rows
$('#removeBtnGrid2').click(function() {
    for (var i = 1; i <= 2; i++) {
        dataViewMG2.deleteItem(i);
    }
    invmodalgrid2.invalidate();
    invmodalgrid2.render();
});
```

and here's the code I'm using to redisplay the Grid (this doesn't work):

```
// XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX Load selected data into MODAL GRID 2 
$('#addBtnGrid1').click(function() {  /// this acts as a cancel btn
    dataViewMG2.beginUpdate();
    dataViewMG2.setItems(modaldata2);
    dataViewMG2.refresh();
    invmodalgrid2.render();
    dataViewMG2.endUpdate();
}
```

What am I doing wrong?   Thanks

Answer (score 1):

First of all you've put `addBtnGrid1` when I think you meant (2) `addBtnGrid2`, second of all are you dealing with a server side to delete your row? Because that doesn't seem to be the proper way of dealing with it (though I have to admit I haven't tried your code). The way I'm dealing with a delete is directly embed the action on the ID itself inside the `columns` definition for the accept/cancel definition as for example this:

```
columns1 = [
            {id:'accnt_name', field:'accnt_name', name: "Account Name", width:90, sortable:true, sorter:sorterStringCompare} },
            {id:"id", name:"", field:"id", width:20, formatter: function (r,c,id,def,datactx){ return "<a href='#' onclick='if (confirm(\"Really Delete?\")) removeClick("+id+","+r+")'><img src='/images/deletex_16.png' border='0' /></a>";} }
        ];
```

and then the function to delete (which call the server side in PHP with AJAX) looks like this:

```
function removeClick(databaseId, gridRow) {
        $.post('myajaxfile.php?action=delete', {id:databaseId}, function(ServerResponse) {
            // if database return an error then display it to the user and undo the cell change
            if(ServerResponse  === undefined) {
                alert("Deleting from database failed...");
            }else {
                if( parseInt(ServerResponse.affected_rows) < 1 || ServerResponse.error_msg != "" ) {                             
                    alert("Deleting from database failed...\n\nERROR Returned: "+ServerResponse.error_msg);
                }else {
                    // success, update the datagrid view on screen
                    var item = dataView1.getItem(gridRow);//RowNum is the number of the row
                    dataView1.deleteItem( item.id );//RowID is the actual ID of the row and not the row number
                    grid1.invalidate();
                    grid1.render();          
                }    
            }   
            $('#loading').hide(); // hide the loading logo                                                                        
        }, "json")
        .fail(function(ServerResponse) { 
            alert("Deleting from database failed...\n\nERROR Returned: "+ServerResponse.responseText);  
            $('#loading').hide(); // hide the loading logo             
        });      
    }
```

So I only refresh (render) the grid if the DELETE went good on the server side...Hope it helps! I don't think showing you the PHP file (server side) for deleting is necessary, but if you do then ask again...

Comment: Thanks    No... this is all done on the client.  Nothing really takes place until the changes are "Saved" since Usr can also "Cancel without saving" so I didn't want to make another trip to the server.  There's also a "Refresh" btn that should redisplay the DataView without any changes.

Comment: Ok I see but nevertheless, you can still use the same technique I have just replace $.post to whichever action you need to do. Triggering the onclick event the way I have it setup is still the best approach, just recode the `removeClick()` function and you're in business

Comment: Ok... I'll give this an upvote but it still didn't solve my issue.  When I use your method (or mine) via deleteItem(), the rows are deleted but I can never redisplay the grid/dataView without resetting everything (browser refresh).  grid.invalidate(), dataView.refresh(), datView.setItems(), etc.  nothing works to redisplay the grid.

Comment: technically you should delete from the dataView object as you said, and invalidate+render the grid object like showing in my example. The only possible I might think of in your situation is... make sure you use the dataview and grid javascript objects you created and NOT the html ID/name of it, just to make sure... and maybe check that you're taking the proper grid1,2,3, whichever grid+dataview number you're at. When you say nothing works, what does it mean exactly anyway? Same data or error thrown, or..something else? Do you also trigger the errors with firebug...

Comment: Thanks... No errors, just no data.  When I empty the grid, I leave the column headers and when I "redisplay" the grid, it's just empty though, of course, the event fires properly (traced in IE developers tools).

Comment: Hmm but you say empty, the `deleteItem()` function should remove only 1 row, though you still have to run both `grid.invalidate()` and `grid.render()`, if you empty the grid of course your data is gone... By the way you don't need to refresh the browser to refresh the grid, just recall your function that loads the data, that's the way I've implemented it with a grid refresh button which is a lot faster then reloading the complete page with browser. Oh and IE is not that great for debugging, you should try out Firefox and the Firebug tool extension for debugging JS and others...

Comment: deleteItem(i) within my for loop removes all rows.  I'm wasn't really emptying the Grid, just the dataView (which I thought was decoupled from the Grid).  IE developertools script debugger reminds me of the excellent FLEX debugger. Firebug's seems extremely obtuse.  I did, however, find a solution that worked for me -  deleteItem(); does remove data from the data object (leaving it with length=0).  However, invalidateRow(i) does not.  When redisplaying the grid I just used grid.invalidate() after updating.  Works perfectly now.

Comment: Glad you found it... `invalidateRow(i)` was not mentionned in your previous code though, they are different indeed. ;)